# How to send data from JSP to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have an HTML page that sends form data to some JSP file & creates a .CSV file of sent data. I need to display that data on an HTML page. How shall I show that data on an HTML page, either by passing that data to the desired HTML page from the JSP or by retrieving that data fron .CSV file?

Comment: Actualy JSP generates HTML, you need to output the formatted HTML data from the JSP.

Comment: ok... trying that way.... :)